# Javascript How to give color using conditional statement based on json array state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, chart.js

As the title suggests, I want to use the chartColors variable to specify colors according to the json state value and give the color value according to the json state value.

```
console.log(functionInfo); // Array(6) : 0 : Lactobacillus  1 :Lactobacillus  2 : Glacagon 3 : toothpaste  4 : toothpaste  5 : Glacagon
console.log(functionStatus); // Array(6) : 0 : "A"            1 : "A"           2 : "B"      3 :  "C"        4 :  "B"        5 : "C"

let chartColors = {
    yellow: "rgb(244, 208, 104)", // A
    green: "#4CC26F", // B
    gray: "#EBEBEB" // C
};

const Function = {
    datasets: [
        {
            backgroundColor: [],
            data: functionInfo // Lactobacillus Lactobacillus Glacagon toothpaste toothpaste Glacagon
        }
    ]
};
```

What if `A` in `functionStatus Array`? I want to give yellow to the backgroundColor .

I would like to create a conditional statement and assign `"A": yellow`, `"B": green`, and `"C" gray` to the array values ​​using the colors in chartColors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below

Keep a color map and iterate using `map` to get the mapped colors list.

```
const colorMap = {
    A: "yellow",
    B: "green",
    C: "gray"
};

let chartColors = {
    yellow: "rgb(244, 208, 104)", // A
    green: "#4CC26F", // B
    gray: "#EBEBEB" // C
};

const Function = {
    datasets: [
        {
            backgroundColor: functionStatus.map((colorCode) => chartColors[colorMap[colorCode]]),
            data: functionInfo // Lactobacillus Lactobacillus Glacagon toothpaste toothpaste Glacagon
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: @ssksksks, check this out!!

Comment: There are no errors and it works right away. thank you.

Comment: If you want to have a lot of thinking and calculation skills while studying JavaScript, the fastest way is to do a lot of projects, right?

Comment: @ssksksks, Yes, hands-on experience is a must.

Comment: Could you please reply here as well, thanks.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69938072/output-the-react-json-array-id-value-and-click-the-id-value-to-execute-the-fu